# How to route components with same links in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React project, I have JSON data as follows:

```
const data = {
  contents: {
    lists: {
      id: 5abcd,
      photo: {
        cover: "url"
      }
    },
    lists: {
      id: 5xyz,
      video: {
        cover: "url"
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Here while routing /contents/list are similar but, when photo or video appended after list gives particular data for video or photo. I'am unable to Route in App.js and it doesn't switch back and gets stuck in Videos component or Photo component

Below is the App.js file

```
<Router>
<Switch>
<Route exact path="/contents/lists/:id1" component={PhotosComp}>
<Route exact path="/contents/lists/:id2" component={VideosComp}>
</Switch>
</Router>
```

How conditional rendering would be done for routing? What if it has id? Any appropriate solution

Comment: You are looking for `exact` prop on `Route` component?

Comment: Your JS object has two `list` properties at the same level of depth. The second one will always overwrite the first.

Comment: I forgt to include :id, please see the edited part. What happens when routing photos it properly goes to PhotosComp but, when routing videos it again goes to PhotosComp i.e it doesn't read id2

Comment: You have two components with the same url. React router will try to match a component for the url "/contents/lists/:id1" and it moves to the first component specified for that url which is PhotosComp in yoyr case. You need to have different urls for different components. Note that react router wont use :id to match the url, it only matches the "/contents/lists/" part